# Peer connection issue with Wireguard

Tags: networking, vpn, raspberry-pi, wireguard

I am requesting your help because I have a Wireguard peer connection issue. I can't figure why. Here is my situation, I have Wireguard server installed on my raspberry pi#1 (home) on docker. I have configured 2 peers. 1 for my phone et 1 for a raspberry#2 in a totally different network (different location).
Wireguard VPN is working well on my phone. But on raspberry#2 I can't reach my home network.

**Configuration on Wireguard server side :**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.1
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = server_private_key
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE

[Peer] (myphone)
PublicKey = myPhone_public_key
PresharedKey = myphone_preshared_key
AllowedIPs = 10.13.13.2/32

[Peer] (raspberry#2)
PublicKey = raspberry#2_public_key
PresharedKey = raspberry#2_preshared_key
AllowedIPs = 10.13.13.3/32
```

**Configuration on Phone side**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.2
PrivateKey = myPhone_private_key
ListenPort = 51820
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_public_key
PresharedKey = myphone_preshared_key
Endpoint = [public_IP]:51820
AllowedIPs = [public_IP], 192.168.1.0/24
```

**Configuration on raspberry#2 side**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.3
PrivateKey = raspberry#2_private_key
ListenPort = 51820
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_public_key
PresharedKey = raspberry#2_preshared_key
Endpoint = [public_IP]:51820
AllowedIPs = [public_IP], 192.168.1.0/24, 10.13.13.0/24
```

**ip route on raspberry#2**

```
default via 192.168.0.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.140 metric 600
10.13.13.0/24 dev wg0 scope link
[public_IP] dev wg0 scope link
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.140 metric 600
192.168.1.0/24 dev wg0 scope link
```

wg0 is Wireguard interface (up and running)

wlan0 is internet access interface (up and running)

192.168.1.0/24 is my home network that I want to access via VPN.

**This is what I already tried :**

1. ping and traceroute from rapsberry#2 to one of my home asset in 192.168.1.0/24 does not return anything
2. ping and traceroute from raspberry#2 to 10.13.13.1 does not return anything
3. ping and traceroute from raspberry#2 to 8.8.8.8 is working well, thanks to split tunneling mode I guess
4. "wg-quick down wg0" on both raspberry#2 and raspberry#1 (wireguard server), then netcat on port 51820 between the 2. The message from raspberry#2 is well received on raspberry#1
5. Add 10.13.13.0/24 in allowed IP in raspberry#2 config, does not change anything.
6. Tried to enable the logs with the command below but the folder does not exist and it seems that I don't have the right kernel

```
# modprobe wireguard 
# echo module wireguard +p > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

As it is working well on my phone, I tend to think that the problem is on raspberry#2 side. As netcat is working well I guess the flow is not blocked at ISP router firewall level, right ?

Now I am clueless. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Update following @Cpt.Whale comment :**

**tcpdump from server side :**

- When I test VPN with my phone, I can see UDP packages coming on port 51280.
- When I test with raspberry#2 with `curl https://[home_asset_ip]:[port]`, and I don't see anything related to vpn package.

**tcpdump from client side (raspberry#2):**

- I can see this request that comes frequently :
  `10.13.13.3.51820 > fvbn-ghf1-1-284-225.w85-125.abo.wanadoo.fr.51820: [bad udp cksum 0x8057 -> 0x1324!] UDP, length 148`
- When I try to access my home asset doing curl, I can see this :
  `10.13.13.3.41874 > [home_asset_IP].[port]: Flags [S], cksum 0xd8f9 (incorrect -> 0xbdc6), seq 2392338409, win 64860, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 811208298 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0`

"fvbn-ghf1-1-284-225.w85-125.abo.wanadoo.fr" (I changed it for privacy) resolves to my public IP. So it tries to reach my VPN server correctly it seems. But how can I interpret the bad UDP checksum ?

**Update: issue solved**

Here is my raspberry#2 configuration that solved my issue :

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.3
PrivateKey = raspberry#2_private_key
ListenPort = 51820
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_public_key
PresharedKey = raspberry#2_preshared_key
Endpoint = [public_IP]:51820
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.0/24, 10.13.13.0/24
```

Thanks @Cpt.Whale for your time and thank you @Justin Ludwig for the solution.

Comment: Packet trace on the server and/or client to verify whether the failing client is sending anything, and compare to the working client. Do you have the same distro on both pi devices? It will be difficult to tell what's happening without debug

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks for your reply. Both raspberry have classic raspbian. It has been installed the same way. Wireguard server is in a docker container, which I think is an Alpine since I can only install package with "apk add" command inside container. I ran tcpdump on both client and server side. I updated my original comment with the result. There are bad UDP checksum error.

Comment: Yeah the checksums being wrong is weird, but it doesn't seem to cause issues other than confusing checksum validations: https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/wireguard/2019-December/004801.html . I found this other thread with a lot of troubleshooting steps specific to wg and pi issues too: https://lore.kernel.org/all/19998b2a9837b44301c733a15fd63ad0@rcrdbrt.com/T/ . But since they're not hitting the server, maybe try tcpdump on the gateway/router to see if either end has some weird firewall behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the endpoint IP address in the `AllowedIPs` setting. `AllowedIPs` is for the IP addresses/networks you want to access through the WireGuard tunnel; if you put the endpoint IP address in this list, you'll end up with a routing loop.

The `AllowedIPs` setting for your raspberry#2 should just be this:

```
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.0/24, 10.13.13.0/24
```

---

Also, you don't need the `DNS` setting in your WireGuard configuration; you only need this setting if you want to use a different DNS configuration when the WireGuard interface is up than when it is down (like when you want to use a custom DNS resolver that is only accessible through the WireGuard tunnel itself).

Comment: Hi @Justin, thank you so much. Removing my endpoint public IP from AllowedIPs solved this. I can now reach my home network. Now that you said it, it make sense I was in routing loop. Thanks!